# how to debug vue3 with vite project in a lerna project on vscode?

Tags: vue.js, debugging, lerna

I make a lerna contain a vue project

How can i debugger this project with vscode?

if vue project is independent I can debug with reference to this documentation:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html